# How to change image side of cursor on drag event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-cursor

When you drag an file on browser screen, an image appear side of mouse cursor that is windows default image. This images is various like `Copy`, `Move` and `Forbide`. See its at bottom.

[image]

How can i change image side of mouse cursor to this images using javascript or JQuery? For example when i drag a file and move mouse in undragable area, `forbiden` image display side of cursor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [dataTransfer.dropEffect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect) property of the `dragover` event to set the small image besides the cursor:

```
$(".targetDiv").on("dragover", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // Shows the "forbidden" image
});
```

The values for that property are `copy`, `move`, `link` and `none`. You can test these values in the code snippet below. Please note that the `originalEvent` must be used. According to my tests, it works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

```js
$(function () {
    $(".targetDiv").on("dragover", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = event.target.getAttribute("data-effect");
    });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Drag a file over each block </p>
<div>
    <div data-effect="link" class="targetDiv">Link</div>
    <div data-effect="move" class="targetDiv">Move</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div data-effect="copy" class="targetDiv">Copy</div>
    <div data-effect="none" class="targetDiv">None</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cursor image by changing the property of the cursor by css using jquery.

```
function ondrag(event) { 
    $('body').css('cursor', 'wait'); 
}
```

You can check the various cursor property here.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

If you want to replace the cursor with a custom image you can use this:
https://github.com/Webbrother/jquery.change-cursor

Comment: Cursor image with drag image different, I want on drag image, no cursor image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit draggables to a certain area,

Try using "containment" option:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment

Comment: It is a link to a manual. If the link dies, the content can either be found again on another page at the same site or the technology is no longer useful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery draggable

Here is the preview what i have done

```js
 $( ".your_image" ).draggable({
 
      drag: function() {
      $(".your_image").css("cursor","url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/16x16/actions/move.png), auto");
      },
      stop: function() {
      
             $(".your_image").css("cursor","url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32x32-free-design-icons/32/Copy.png), auto");
      }
    });
```

```css
.your_image{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  cursor:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32x32-free-design-icons/32/Copy.png), auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="your_image">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="log">

</div>
```